# Retrieve specific JSON properties from JSON collection in SQL Server column using a SQL query

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I am struggling to find a solution to retrieve specific properties from a JSON collection which is stored in a SQL Server table's column.

Please see my table structure here:

```
Id: int
ItemDetails: NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

Below is how the table would be populated. Apologies I couldn't make it show in the HTML Table format as there is no way to Insert JSON in the tabular format in stackoverflow.

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [ { "name": "Sam", "age": 14, "gender": "Male" }, { "name": "Sandra", "age": 15, "gender": "Female" } ] |
| 2 | [ { "name": "Tom", "age": 22, "gender": "Male" }, { "name": "Caroline", "age": 25, "gender": "Female" } ] |

Now I want to write a SQL query to get output like this:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam |
| 1 | Sandra |
| 2 | Tom |
| 2 | Caroline |

If the `ItemDetails` column didn't store a JSON collection, but instead a single JSON object, then this can be achievable using `JSON_VALUE`. However because it contains a collection, I haven't been able to crack it.

I have tried using `JSON_EXTRACT` or `JSON_QUERY` as well but all in to no vain. Please could someone assist here?

Comment: Please, post your current attempt. As a hint, you may try `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema to parse the stored JSON content. Also note, that the posted JSON example is invalid JSON.

Comment: @Zhorov JSON now has been validated. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try to parse this JSON content with `OPENJSON()` and explicit schema:

```
SELECT v.Id, j.Name, j.Age
FROM (VALUES
   (1, N'[ { "name":"Sam", "age":14, "gender":"Male" }, { "name":"Sandra", "age":15, "gender":"Female" } ]'),
   (2, N'[ { "name":"Tom", "age":22, "gender":"Male" }, { "name":"Caroline", "age":25, "gender":"Female" } ]')
) v (Id, ItemDetails)
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(v.ItemDetails) WITH (
   Name nvarchar(100) '$.name',
   Age int '$.age'
   -- add additional columns definitions
) j
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time out to help me with this. I have tried and tested the above and it works.  This is exactly what i needed :)